# How to perform click event on anchor tags

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I am working on asp.net using c#. I have one master page with  3 anchor tag links and one html label. When a user clicks on a particular link it should redirect to specific page and the link text should be displayed on the label. I have used following code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#div1 a').click(function () {
                if (focus == true)
                    $('#lblHeader').text("Home");
            });
            $('#blog').click(function () {
                if (focus == true)
                    $('#lblHeader').text("Blog");
            });
            $('#about').click(function () {
                if (focus == true)
                    $('#lblHeader').text("About");
            });
        });
```

please guide me.

Comment: what is your issue here ? and where the focus is defined ?

Comment: is the label on the master page?

Comment: yes my label is on master page only and i need to use only client side code.

Comment: i ran into the same thing, my answer should help

Comment: really not clear what behavior of links needs to be, if want next page to show value need to either use cookie, localStorage or send data to server

Comment: it is pure clientside situation. whenever user clicks on anchor tag link it inner text would assigned to html label value.

Comment: @user999689: If you change the label and then redirect to a specific page, what do you want the label to do - since the user is no longer on the page?

Comment: label present in master page. it just acts as a redirected page title bar. ex. for about.aspx it show About Us etc.

Comment: I edited my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a label server control, changing the text with javascript before a postback occurs will have no effect since the whole page is redrawn.

**Edit**: I think I know what you are trying to do. Why not create a `contentplaceholder` in your master page, and set its value in each of the pages?

In your Master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" %>
...
<asp:contentplaceholder id="PageLabel" runat="server" />
```

In each content page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageLabel" Runat="Server" >
    Home <!--or about, or blog-->
</asp:content>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting your problem right , the labels are on the Master page and $('#lblHeader') is not accessing the labels properly, possibly because asp.net changes the id's of labels that are of master page - try this:

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#div1 a').click(function () {
            if (focus == true)
                 $('[id$=lblHeader]').text("Home");
        });
        $('#blog').click(function () {
            if (focus == true)
                 $('[id$=lblHeader]').text("Blog");
        });
        $('#about').click(function () {
            if (focus == true)
                 $('[id$=lblHeader]').text("About");
        });
    });
```

or store that value in hidden field, and in document.ready of the client page assign the value to the label - using the id I provided

Answer (score 0):

If you want user to see something after clicking a link you need to prevent browser default and set a timer for duration you want.

This won't provide a very good user experience!

```
$('#div1 a, #blog, #about').click(function() {
    if (focus == true) {
        $('[id$=lblHeader]').text("Home");
        var href = this.href
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location = href;
        }, 2000);
        return false;
    }

});
```